# How to force sql server user stored procedures to not be created as a system stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I've created Brent Ozar's SP_Blitz and SP_BlitzIndex stored procedures in all of my SQL Server 2005, 2008, and 2008 R2 database servers.  All of the SP_Blitz stored procedures were created as user stored procedures, but the SP_BlitzIndex stored procedures were created as system stored procedures in every server.  The owner of all of these stored procedures is dbo.  I've also created SP_Who3 and SP_WhoIsActive stored procedures and they were all created as user stored procedures.  Does anyone have an idea why this is happening, and how to force the SP_BlitzIndex stored procedures to be created as user stored procedures?

Comment: You shouldn't start a name of a user stored procedured `sp_` that designates system stored procs. I use `usp_` for user stored procs. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172115(v=vs.100).aspx for more details.

Comment: My only regret is that @Fred commented instead of answered. If this had been an answer, I would be able to downvote for being completely incorrect.

Comment: @JeremiahPeschka I wasn't answering the question just commenting on the naming convention being used. I wasn't saying this was the reason for the OP's problem hence a comment and not an answer. The comment is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Brent Ozar himself here.

My cofounder Kendra Little wrote sp_BlitzIndex™, and she chose to create it as a system stored procedure. If you look at the source code, here's the line involved:

```
EXEC sys.sp_MS_marksystemobject 'dbo.sp_BlitzIndex';
```

If you don't want it created as a system stored procedure, you can just uncomment that line.

Hope you enjoy our free tools!

Comment: I'm planning to remove that in the next version anyway-- current versions should work fine if the line is just commented out.